# Agda and Binary Search Trees

Tags: agda

Just a note, this is for an assignment, so probably best not to post complete solutions, rather, I'm just stuck and need some hints as to what I should be looking at next.

```
module BST where

open import Data.Nat
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Relation.Binary
open DecTotalOrder decTotalOrder using () renaming (refl to ≤-refl; trans to ≤-trans)


data Ord (n m : ℕ) : Set where
  smaller : n < m -> Ord n m
  equal   : n ≡ m -> Ord n m
  greater : n > m -> Ord n m

cmp : (n m : ℕ) -> Ord n m
cmp zero zero       = equal refl
cmp zero (suc n)    = smaller (s≤s z≤n)
cmp (suc n) zero    = greater (s≤s z≤n)
cmp (suc n) (suc m) with cmp n m 
... | smaller n<m-pf = smaller (s≤s n<m-pf)
... | equal   n≡m-pf = equal (cong suc n≡m-pf)
... | greater n>m-pf = greater (s≤s n>m-pf)


-- To keep it simple and to exclude duplicates,
-- the BST can only store [1..]
--
data BST (min max : ℕ) : Set where
  branch : (v : ℕ)
         → BST min v → BST v max 
         → BST min max
  leaf   : min < max -> BST min max
```

These are already imported:

```
≤-refl : ∀ {a} → a ≤ a 

≤-trans : ∀ {a b c} → a ≤ b → b ≤ c → a ≤ c
```

We need to implement this function which widens the bounds of the BST:

```
widen : ∀{min max newMin newMax}
      → BST min max
      → newMin ≤ min
      → max ≤ newMax
      → BST newMin newMax
```

I have this so far:

```
widen : ∀{min max newMin newMax}
      → BST min max
      → newMin ≤ min
      → max ≤ newMax
      → BST newMin newMax
widen (leaf min<max-pf) newMin<min-pf max<newMax-pf = BST newMin<min-pf max<newMax-pf
widen (branch v l r) newMin<min-pf max<newMax = branch v 
                                                (widen l newMin<min-pf max<newMax) 
                                                (widen r newMin<min-pf max<newMax)
```

Now this obviously doesn't work because the new bounds don't have to be strictly less / greater than the min / max. A hint was given: `It is not strictly necessary, but you may find it helpful to implement an auxiliary function that widens the range of a strictly smaller than relation of the form min < max.` Which is kind of what I've done here, obviously I'd need to change a few things around, but I think the basic idea is there.

This is where I'm at, and I'm just really stuck as to where to go from here, I've done as much research as I can, but there's not a whole lot of reading material out there for using Agda. Do I perhaps need to use ≤-refl or ≤-trans?

Comment: As a hint for the `leaf` part: the auxiliary function should have type `∀ {a b c d} → a ≤ b → b < c → c ≤ d → a < d`. This quite easily follows from the fact that `≤` is transitive over ℕ. `≤-trans` has type `∀ {a b c} → a ≤ b → b ≤ c → a ≤ c`, `<` is defined as `m < n = suc m ≤ n`. It should be fairly easy from here.

Comment: I noticed that you've included a chunk of code that "doesn't work", which is something I haven't seen in Agda in ages. It suggests that you might not be using the emacs Agda-mode, which is the single greatest thing since sliced bread. I hate emacs, and only use it for its Agda-mode, simply because its features (holes, automatic pattern matching, type information) make writing complex Agda possible. I apologize if you were already using it, but if you aren't, try it out and I'm sure you'll have a much easier time with your assignments.

Comment: For the `branch` case, if you were using the interactive mode and holes, you'd likely see that your recursive calls to `widen` don't really have argument types that make sense. You're going to need `≤-refl` somewhere :)

Comment: @copumpkin: Argh! I knew agda-mode is very useful, but this.. I need to fix my emacs on Win 7. :D

Answer (score 4):

The tricky part here is understanding what the `widen` function actually needs to change. Once you got that, writing the code is fairly easy.

Let's start with the `leaf` part, we have:

```
widen (leaf min<max) newMin≤min max≤newMax = {! !}
```

`leaf min<max` has type `BST min max`. After applying `widen`, we want the tree to have type `BST newMin newMax` - that means we have to change the proof `min < max` to `newMin < newMax`.

Luckily we know that `newMin ≤ min` and `max ≤ newMax`. `≤` is transitive (it follows from the fact, that `≤` forms a total order over ℕ) and from that it quite easily follows that `newMin ≤ newMax` - that is nice and all, but we have to tell that to Agda.

That's where `≤-trans` comes into play. Recall that:

```
≤-trans : ∀ {a b c} → a ≤ b → b ≤ c → a ≤ c
```

That is the definition of transitivity! Exactly what we're looking for. The (rather small) problem is that our proofs use `<` alongside `≤`. If they didn't

```
trans-4 : ∀ {a b c d} → a ≤ b → b ≤ c → c ≤ d → a ≤ d
```

would be fairly easy to write (you just have to apply `≤-trans` twice). You might want to actually write this function, it will help you with the next part.

We know that `a ≤ b` (`newMin ≤ min`) and `c ≤ d` (`max ≤ newMax`), but we only know `b < c` - we cannot just apply `≤-trans` twice. Looking at `Data.Nat`, we find that

```
_<_ : Rel ℕ Level.zero
m < n = suc m ≤ n
```

So what we *really* want to write is this:

```
trans-4 : ∀ {a b c d} → a ≤ b → suc b ≤ c → c ≤ d → suc a ≤ d
```

That's a bit harder, so let's break it into two steps. We need to prove that:

```
trans₁ : ∀ {a b c} → a ≤ b → suc b ≤ c → suc a ≤ c -- a ≤ b → b < c → a < c
trans₂ : ∀ {a b c} → suc a ≤ b → b ≤ c → suc a ≤ c -- a < b → b ≤ c → a < c
```

We *could* use `≤-trans` if we had `suc a ≤ suc b` instead of just `a ≤ b`. But we can get that! If `a ≤ b`, then surely `a + 1 ≤ b + 1`. Quick look at standard library again:

```
data _≤_ : Rel ℕ Level.zero where
  z≤n : ∀ {n}                 → zero  ≤ n
  s≤s : ∀ {m n} (m≤n : m ≤ n) → suc m ≤ suc n
```

I leave the rest as an exercise. Once you know that `newMin < newMax`, reconstructing the proof in `leaf` becomes trivial.

---

The `branch` part is actually much easier to write in Agda and of course, the tricky part is figuring out what proofs we need to change.

We have:

```
widen (branch v l r) newMin≤min max≤newMax = {! !}
```

Again, `branch v l r` has type `BST min max` and we want `BST newMin newMax`. As you noticed, we need to create a new branch and recursively widen `l` and `r`.

If we want to recursively apply `widen`, we better check what are the types of `l` and `r`:

```
l : BST min v
r : BST v max
```

Because this answer is already rather long, I'm going to discuss the `l` subtree, the other case is symmetric.

The problem is of course that if we apply `widen` to `l`, we need to also provide two new proofs. `min` hasn't changed, so we can just pass `newMin≤min` as the first one. What about the second one? We can no longer give it `max≤newMax`, because our subtree is `BST min v` rather than `BST min max`.

Our final tree must look like `BST newMin newMax` and we know it must contain `v`. This gives us only one choice for type of widened left subtree - `BST newMin v`.

What does that mean? The type of second proof is thus `v ≤ v` and it's easy from here!

Happy coding!

Comment: This is just a quick question but would using suc a <= suc b imply that the definition of trans1 should be altered to be trans₁ : ∀ {a b c} → suc a ≤ suc b → suc b ≤ c → suc a ≤ c. Because if we did this wouldn't we need to change the widen function to take in suc newMin <= suc min as its second argument instead of newMin <= min which was the definition of widen given for the assignment.

Comment: @Abstract: I wanted the function to be easy to use, i.e. you just give it `newMin≤min`, `min<max` and `max≤newMax` and you're done. Of course, turning `a ≤ b` into `suc a ≤ suc b` is easy, you just apply `s≤s` constructor to it - that's why I copied the definition of `_≤_`.