# Turning a <= b to suc a <= suc b

Tags: equality, agda

This is an extension of the question posted here:

[Agda and Binary Search Trees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10862478/agda-and-binary-search-trees)

I have

```
trans₁ : ∀ {a b c} → suc a ≤ suc b → suc b ≤ c → suc a ≤ c
```

for the definition of `trans₁`, but this would require me to change the definition of widen below to:

```
widen : ∀{min max newMin newMax}
      → BST min max
      → suc newMin ≤ suc min
      → max ≤ newMax
      → BST newMin newMax
```

How would i change `a <= b` to `suc a <= suc b`? This would then allow me to change the definition of `trans₁` to:

```
trans₁ : ∀ {a b c} → a ≤ b → suc b ≤ c → suc a ≤ c
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the s<=s constructor for the less than or equal to relation. Please ask on the course forums, not on stack overflow.